# Angular2 localization reload component HTML

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am working on an Angular2 app, which has multiple languages. Depending on the cookies that are sent with my angular2 template request, I get different language templates from the server. The problem is that when I change the language in Angular, it does not reload the @Component HTML-s, which means that I am not getting the translated page templates.

Example

Working in EN, I have a template

```
<p>Hello: @{{ user.name }}</p>
```

When I change my language in Angular, I have to reload the component HTML to get (for example) the German translation template.

```
<p>Guten tag: @{{ user.name }}</p>
```

Any suggestions on, which class I have to use to do this? I figure it has to be easier than refreshing the whole page?

I am currently just doing a

```
location.reload();
```

after changing the language, but I cannot figure out a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 is planning to adopt localization by default in the future. But, for now, why don't you use [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) to translate things?

It's [easy to set up](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#usage) and you can easily translate terms using pipes:

`{{ 'HELLO' | translate}}`

Then, you just create localization files inside your `i18n` folders with all translations you need (e.g. `en.json`, `de.json`, etc.).

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/btpW3l0jr5beJVjohy1Q?p=preview) for a simple working example.